# Firebase Hosting rewrites set up to pass all other URL to a particular Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a NextJS app and an express.js API both hosted in Firebase Cloud Functions.

This is my firebase.json

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "src/public",
        "rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "/user",
                "function": "api"
            },
            {
                "source": "/users",
                "function": "api"
            },
            {
                "source": "**/**",
                "function": "next"
            }
        ]
    },
    "functions": {
        "source": "src/functions"
    }
}
```

What I expecting was to rewrite `/user` and `/users` to `api` Cloud Function and all other URL to `next` Cloud Function. But it not working as I expected. Every URL is passing to `next` Cloud Function even `/user` and `/users`.
And I need help...

Comment: What exactly is not working the way you expect?  Please be specific.  Is it one of the rewrites?  Or all three? What is actually happening in the case that it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: every url is using next cloud function even /user and /users

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code, you can find its used on an example of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) that is intended for requests to files or directories that do not exist, including all other replies I understand

```
// Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
 "source": "**",
 "function": "next"
```

Comment: what behavior you got in your app with the above code?